# windows server 2008 - can't start services, no networking after update

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

My Windows Server 2008 gone crazy after update.

Windows interface showing that physical link is not connected, but it is connected, I can ping him, I can ping from console any avialable hostname (and it resolves). Network settings window is empty, with endless loading animation.

I can't start any service - its failed without any message (or event) after several minutes.
Can't install or uninstall programs (error message of "unexpected error").

Server role manager window (that loads at startup) stuck in "Loading data..." in fields with info.

I deleted those new updates is safe mode, (except .NET Framework 3.5, it won't let me uninstall it), but server still in this state.

Please help. Im already spent about 30 hours of trying, googling and so on, but without any result. If you experienced something like this, or have any thoughts I will be happy for any comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this. 
`sc querylock` showed me that there service *.\NT Service Control Manager* makes a service base deadlock and other services can't start.

Found a perfect solution here: http://darktraining.com/windows/63/

Comment: This link is dead, can you tell me what you did to resolve this issue please?

Comment: It depends. You can use `sc querylock` to find out what was locked and then find solution - apply hotfix, disable or whatever. Most of it can be googled I think. Sorry, can't remember what was that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the OP's link has changed structure, here is the new link

https://darktraining.com/2010/06/18/Windows-2008-server-services-wont-start-after-reboot/